# Different card size

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, cardview

How can I make it so that in the `recycleView` there are differents size cards? (1x1, 1x2 and 2x1 where 1 is the card length)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59emj.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GridLayoutManager` with different span count.
Here is some example.

In activity:

```
//Initialize recyclerView and adapter before
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                    if (adapter.isHeader(position)) {
                        //Returns span count 2 if method isHeader() returns true. 
                        //You can use your own logic here.
                        return  mLayoutManager.getSpanCount()
                    } else {
                         return 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

And add this method to your adapter class:

```
public boolean isHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;//you can use some other logic in here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create two view holders. One of them holds the two cards that are in the same row, the other holds the full row one. It would definitely look like the image you posted.   For implementing the recycler view with multiple view holders check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type).